# Blender script for turning on curve profile with crown molding preset

Tags: scripting, bezier-curves

I am making a simple script that either turns off bevel geometry for a curve or turns it on with a Crown molding preset. My problem is that it seems to not be possible to set the preset, at least not in the way I would have thought. Can anyone help me fix the preset line? Here is my code:

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Check if the active object is a curve
if obj and obj.type == 'CURVE':
    # Check if the curve already has a bevel
    if obj.data.bevel_depth != 0.0:
        # Set bevel to 0.0 radius
        obj.data.bevel_depth = 0.0
    else:
        # Set bevel to profile preset crown with 0.25 radius
        obj.data.bevel_depth = 0.25
        obj.data.bevel_profile = 'CROWN'
```